# API design Python

Tags: python, api

I have found a very nice talk by Joshua Bloch:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw

http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf

While it is fairly general, some comments are only valid to statically typed languages. I am looking for something equivalent for Python.
([This](http://ep2011.europython.eu/conference/talks/good-api-design) talk looks promising but has not been given yet)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps one of these (or both).

- [PyCon 2011: API Design: Lessons Learned by Hettinger](http://pyvideo.org/video/366/pycon-2011--api-design--lessons-learned)
- [PyCon 2011: API Design anti-patterns by Alex Martelli](http://pyvideo.org/video/445/pycon-2011--api-design-anti-patterns)

Comment: In my humble opinion, the first one's good, the second one is too much blabber.